# iOS detect touch screen while display is off

Tags: ios

Is it possible to detect touching/tap the screen in iOS while the device's screen is off? something running in background and count the number of touch and save it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the device is in sleep mode ie you turned it off then no but you might be able to keep the device on just turn the screen off so it still thinks that it is on just no display output. - you could even just bodge it to display black. just an idea

Comment: 1 more idea than you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible. Due to power saving reasons.

Comment: It is not possible even the user accepts the issue?